# .isVisible() method not working for JFrame

Tags: java, jframe

I've created a GUI, I included the 2 methods I'll be needing below. As you can see when I click the button the Menu's visibility is set to false. I want to do something on the other program but ONLY when the button has been clicked, and the frame has disappeared. For demonstration purposes I made my program keep spitting out millions of lines of "GUI Visible", until the Menu is set to invisible, where it should change to spitting out "GUI hiding".

```
public class Menu extends javax.swing.JFrame {
public Menu() {
    initComponents();
}
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    try {
        this.WriteToText();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Menu.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}                                        

 public void WriteToText() throws Exception
 {

     FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("playerdetails.txt");
 BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
 bw.write(playername.getText());
     System.out.println("Printed");
     clicked = "1";
     this.setVisible(false); //HERE
```

This is the program where I am running the menu from. It would appear as though the "hm.isVisible();" method I used isn't working. When I run it, the program says that the GUI is hiding regardless of whether it is hiding or not. By using S.o.pl's I established that the method always returns a value of false. How can I get it to return the right value??

```
package monster.defense;
import java.io.*;
public class MonsterDefense{
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

    Menu hm = new Menu(); 
    hm.setvisible(true);
    BufferedReader pdetails = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("playerdetails.txt"));
    BufferedReader inKb = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (System.in));

    int yum = 1;
    while(yum == 1)
    {
        if(hm.isVisible()==true) //HERE
        {
            System.out.println("GUI visible");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("GUI hiding");
        }
    }
    String cat = inKb.readLine();
    System.out.println("here"+hm.getPName());

  }
}
```

Comment: Just to let you know you don't need to do `hm.isVisible()==true` you can just do `if(hm.isVisible()) {`

Comment: @MitchWeaver By clicking the button on the GUI.

Comment: You should add a `sleep(1)` (at least) to save some CPU in your `while` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, once I made you code runnable, it run just fine for me.

However, it's the wrong approach, instead of using a while loop, which could potentially block the Event Dispatching Thread, making it impossible to close the window (or interact with your UI) at all, you should be using a modal dialog instead, for example...

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                Menu menu = new Menu();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, menu, "PlayerName", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

                String playerName = menu.getPlayerName();

                // Now you can write it to the file if you need

            }
        });
    }

    public class Menu extends JPanel {

        private JTextField playerName;

        public Menu() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            playerName = new JTextField(10);
            add(new JLabel("Player name: "));
            add(playerName);
        }

        public String getPlayerName() {
            return playerName.getText();
        }
    }

}
```

Have a look at [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more details

Comment: Would anyone care to enlighten me as to the reason for the downvote? In what way does the question not answer the OP's question? How might it be improved? In your opinion, what is wrong with the answer

Answer (score 0):

create a custom boolean inside the Main class. if you are not sure with `isVisible()`

```
class Main{

boolean opened = false;

public void setOpen(boolean open){
this.opened = open;
}

public Boolean isOpened(){
return opened;
}

}
```

in the logic that you have in main method can now check

```
if(hm.isOpened()){
}
```

when you are opening the frame call the method

```
hm.setOpen(true); along with the `setVisible(true);`
```

Comment: In my bottom program where I wrote hm.run();, the menu is set to visible.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [tutorial on Swing Component listeners](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/componentlistener.html) and move your logic to the `componentHidden()` and `componentShow()` listener methods.

Edit: As @MadProgrammer noted, `WindowListener` would be appropriate if you want to intercept window closing/opening events. It also [has a tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/windowlistener.html).
You'd probably want to check the `windowActivated()` / `windowDeactivated()` methods.

Comment: A `WindowListener` might be more suitable

Comment: @MadProgrammer you're right, I edited to include that  tutorial too. Though `ComponentListener` should work as well, but I don't have a compiler to test it at the moment :/